# Elapsed time PerfTips while debugging in Visual Studio 2022 isn't working in Docker

Tags: docker, visual-studio, elapsed

I have a .net core project that I deploy in Docker for Desktop.

I can debug the project with breakpoints but the Elapsed time PerfTips is not showing up between lines.

I have the problem only when I launch it from the Docker config.

launchsettings.json

```
  "profiles": {
    "MyAppName": {
      "commandName": "Project",
 ...
    "Docker": {
      "commandName": "Docker",
 ...
```

If I select the MyAppName config the Elapsed time is showing up though but would be hard to have all the config I need with it (volumes & ports).

This is enabled:
Options | Debugging | [x] Show elapsed time PerfTip while debugging